# RefenceError: UET is not defined

Tags: javascript, bing, tracking-pixel

I'm struggling to understand why this javascript error keeps popping up on my website and I can't reproduce it.
I've followed the bing documentation to install their tracking pixel so I have this in my header :

```
  <script>
    (function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){
      var o={ti:"xxxxxxxx"};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),
              w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r, n.async=1,
            n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;
              s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},
            i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})
    (window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");
  </script>
```

However in some browsers, the UET variable in this code, which is loaded by the url given as the `r` variable, seems to not be defined while it's only called when the url is loaded...

If anybody can make sense of it before I reach out to bing, I'll be very thankful!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Building on the accepted answer, I believe there might a way to prevent these errors.

Do you see the bit that says `w[u]=new UET(o)` in the script? We know that `w` means `window` there. And UET is an object created on the global scope (that is, on the global `window` object), thus it's existence can be tested with `window.UET` (try running `window.UET` on the console with and without loading the script, you'll see the former case returns `undefined`  and latter case returns a function `function UET(o) {...}`. So, technically, you can alter the script putting a conditional there, like the following:

```
if(w.UET){w[u]=new w.UET(o)}
```

Here's my attempt to deconstruct the relatively cryptic looking `<script>` to a more readable function call for better visibility of what's happening there (this may also come handy if you're using it in an SPA like I do):

```
function initMicrosoftUET(
  w,
  d,
  t = "script",
  r = "//bat.bing.com/bat.js",
  u = "uetq"
) {
  var f, n, i;
  w[u] = w[u] || [];

  f = function () {
    var o = { ti: "xxxxxxxx" };
    o.q = w[u];
    if (w.UET) w[u] = new w.UET(o) || [];
    w[u].push("pageLoad");
  }

  n = d.createElement(t);
  n.src = r;
  n.async = 1;
  n.onload = n.onreadystatechange = function () {
    var s = this.readyState;

    (s && s !== "loaded" && s !== "complete") || f();

    n.onload = n.onreadystatechange = null;
  }

  i = d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];
  i.parentNode.insertBefore(n, i);
};

initMicrosoftUET(window, document);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's actually more the kind of answer I was looking for ;) 
Works like a charm!

Answer (score 7):

Ad/tracker blocking.

If the user blocks the domain `bat.bing.com`, then `UET` never gets defined.

For example, FireFox console on accessing a website that contributes to Bing tracking while blocking such things:
[image: FireFox console with Bing tracking blocked]

---

As for 'fixing' it, in my view the most appropriate fix is to ignore it*. If you're seeing it in Sentry.io or similar, the single occurrence can be ignored rather than all undefined variable errors (which of course you wouldn't want to blanket-ignore).

The user is deliberately blocking it, and the error isn't user-visible, (without opening the console) so nothing to worry about.

<sub>*Of course, you could always not load trackers for any of your users ;)</sub>

Comment: Please add a source to justify how ignoring this specific error counts as fixing it!

Comment: @IngoSteinke I said 'in my view', what better source for *my view* could I possibly give you than me saying it?

Comment: what specific experience or sources brought you to that view? It's probably more than just a random opinion if you're so specific about the solution.