# Deconstruct bing uetq tag for microsoft advertising, in order to use it with angular universal and renderer2

Tags: javascript, html, angular, bing

###### Expected result:

After the user accepts tracking cookies and thus the method at the heart of this question is called: the bing script is loaded in a way that works well with angular (universal) in typescript

###### Input:

I got this tag from the microsoft advertising page.

```
<script>(function(w,d,t,r,u){var f,n,i;w[u]=w[u]||[],f=function(){var o={ti:"123456789", enableAutoSpaTracking: true};o.q=w[u],w[u]=new UET(o),w[u].push("pageLoad")},n=d.createElement(t),n.src=r,n.async=1,n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=function(){var s=this.readyState;s&&s!=="loaded"&&s!=="complete"||(f(),n.onload=n.onreadystatechange=null)},i=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0],i.parentNode.insertBefore(n,i)})(window,document,"script","//bat.bing.com/bat.js","uetq");</script>
```

###### What I tried:

I have deconstructed the code similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64172509/7225462) and put it in a service:

```
    private setMsftScript(renderer: Renderer2) {
    const url = "//bat.bing.com/bat.js";
    const uetq = "uetq"
    window[uetq] = window[uetq] || [];

    const f = function () {
      var o = { ti: "123456789", enableAutoSpaTracking: true };
      o['q'] = window[uetq];
      if (window["UET"]) window[uetq] = new window["UET"](o) || [];
      window[uetq].push("pageLoad");
    }

    const script = renderer.createElement('script');
    renderer.setAttribute(script, 'id', 'microsoft');
    renderer.setProperty(script, 'type', 'text/javascript');
    renderer.setProperty(script, 'async', true);
    renderer.setProperty(
      script,
      'src',
      url
    );

    renderer.appendChild(document.head, script);
    f();
  };
```

This should put the script into the head using renderer2, which is recommended for angular afaiu.

###### Problem

I have not fully grasped what is going on with the function simply called f(). It is called once when the script is loaded ("onload") but also when its readyState changes (I cannot find anything about readyState of a script element online), and it also seems to do some checks against the ready state of the document itself (it checks against "loaded" which I cannot find in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState)).

###### Desired Output

In my scenario (I add the script to the head after user accepted cookies in cookie banner), will simply calling f() myself (as seen above) once be equivalent to whatever microsoft is doing in the js version? If not how can I do the same as msft for my use-case in an angular app?